# How do I send HTML email using linux 'mail' command?

Tags: email, html, mail-command

`mail -s "subject" xxxxx@gmail.com <test.html`
works, but only for plain text email.

What is the correct way to send HTML email using the Linux command `mail`?

Comment: The scripts here are fine for simple English text with short lines, but proper MIME support requires you to handle non-ASCII character sets and arbitrarily long lines by wrapping them properly. In short, you _can_ assemble a valid MIME structure with `echo` and `cat`, but for many real-world scenarios, you really really don't want to.

Answer (score 74):

There are many different versions of `mail` around. When you go beyond `mail -s subject to1@address1 to2@address2 <body` (for sending, that's all [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/mailx.html) guarantees — and even `-s` didn't exist in the [old days](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_8th/1/mail)), they tend to have different command line options. Adding an additional header isn't always easy.

- With some `mailx` implementations, e.g. [from `mailutils` on Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/mail.1.html) or [Debian's `bsd-mailx`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=bsd-mailx&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+6.0+squeeze&format=html&locale=en), it's easy, because there's an option for that.

  ```
  mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/html' -s "Subject" to@address <test.html
  ```
- With the [Heirloom](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/) [`mailx`](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html), there's no convenient way. One possibility to insert arbitrary headers is to set `editheaders=1` and use an external editor (which can be a script).

  ```
  ## Prepare a temporary script that will serve as an editor.
  ## This script will be passed to ed.
  temp_script=$(mktemp)
  cat <<'EOF' >>"$temp_script"
  1a
  Content-Type: text/html
  .
  $r test.html
  w
  q
  EOF
  ## Call mailx, and tell it to invoke the editor script
  EDITOR="ed -s $temp_script" heirloom-mailx -S editheaders=1 -s "Subject" to@address <<EOF
  ~e
  .
  EOF
  rm -f "$temp_script"
  ```
- With a general [POSIX `mailx`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/mailx), I don't know how to get at headers.

If you're going to use any `mail` or `mailx`, keep in mind that

- This isn't portable even within a given Linux distribution. For example, both Ubuntu and Debian have several alternatives for `mail` and `mailx`.
- When composing a message, `mail` and `mailx` treats lines beginning with `~` as commands. If you pipe text into `mail`, you need to arrange for this text not to contain lines beginning with `~`.

If you're going to install software anyway, you might as well install something more predictable than `mail`/`Mail`/`mailx`. For example, [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/). With Mutt, you can supply most headers in the input with the `-H` option, [but not `Content-Type`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83137/trying-to-send-html-mail-on-mac-osx-mountain-lion/83138#83138), which needs to be set via a mutt option.

```
mutt -e 'set content_type=text/html' -s 'hello' 'to@address' <test.html
```

Or you can invoke **`sendmail`** directly. There are several versions of `sendmail` out there, but they all support `sendmail -t` to send a mail in the simplest fashion, reading the list of recipients from the mail. (I think they don't all support `Bcc:`.) On most systems, `sendmail` isn't in the usual `$PATH`, it's in `/usr/sbin` or `/usr/lib`.

```
cat <<'EOF' - test.html | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
To: to@address
Subject: hello
Content-Type: text/html

EOF
```

Comment: Tried using the mutt example above; substituting real values for the filename, to email address, etc. but got "No recipients were specified"  I'm very new to mutt, @Gilles do you know why that might have happened? (osx mountain lion, mutt 1.5.21 installed via homebrew)

Comment: my second line was "To: myaddress@mycompany.com" (sorry for lack of formatting, not possible in a response, actual text was sans quotes) and I included a blank line before putting in the EOF.   would there be configuration I need to do to mutt?  prior to trying the example you gave (with proper values substituted) all I did was 'brew install mutt'

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden Ask a new question. Copy-paste the exact command you ran and the full error message. See if you can send an email from mutt using the interactive interface.

Comment: I was able to send something via the 'interactive' interface,  it initially complained about a mail directory missing and offered to create it. reminded how much I hate vim ;-)  but got it to send.  I'll start a new question as that is easier to format etc.  The exact error message was just what I said "No recipients were specified."

Comment: New question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83137/trying-to-send-html-mail-on-mac-osx-mountain-lion

Answer (score 16):

```
#!/bin/sh

(
echo "To: me@example.com"
echo "Subject: hello"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo
echo "<html><b><font size='7'>H</font>ello</b></html>"
echo
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Comment: That doesn't acually use `mail`.

Comment: @user16144 No, but it's a nice alternative that the OP might like to consider.

Comment: Yes, it does not use mail but it works everywhere I have tried it which is more than I can say for the other solutions.

Comment: Works beautifully on Mac as well.

Answer (score 7):

With the Heirloom mailx, convenient way is

```
mailx -s "$(echo -e "Newsletter issue 3\nContent-Type: text/html")" user@server.com < /tmp/htmlmail.txt
```

Thanks, [Dude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5822182/2694796)
Tested on Fedora 17, and worked

Comment: Cheeky.  I like it. :-]

Comment: Beware that this solution may lead to the email having *both* "Content-Type: text/html" and "Content-Type: text/plain", and potential inconsistencies if you use this way to specify charset.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to add `Content-Type` header to your email to make this happen.

```
echo "<html><b>Hello</b></html>" | mail -a "Content-type: text/html;" -s "Testing" me@example.com
```

will work

Comment: mail: illegal option -- a

Comment: Do you have `mailx`? That might have the option. If that doesn't work. If that doesn't work, you can consider using mutt although I don't know off hand what the command line switches to do it are.

Comment: if mail isn't cutting the mustard, use python ... http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html examples is the 3rd one or #6 which suits your requirement.

Comment: Python will require you to write (and maintain) a script. A command line one liner has different advantages.

Comment: I have mailx,but "option -a" don't work,still show:mail: illegal option -- a

Comment: I have the `mail` command in Arch Linux provided by the `s-nail` package, and the `-a` option is entirely different.

Comment: The Debian/Ubuntu package that provides mail with a `-a` option is `bsd-mailx`.  Doesn't support attachments though.

Answer (score 3):

With heirloom-mailx you can change sendmail program to your hook script, replace headers there and then use sendmail.

The script I use (`~/bin/sendmail-mailx-hook`):

```
#!/bin/bash

sed '1,/^$/{
s,^\(Content-Type: \).*$,\1text/html; charset=utf-8,g
s,^\(Content-Transfer-Encoding: \).*$,\18bit,g
}' | sendmail $@
```

This script changes the values in the mail header as follows:

- `Content-Type:` to `text/html; charset=utf-8`
- `Content-Transfer-Encoding:` to `8bit` (not sure if this is really needed).

To send HTML email:

```
mailx -Ssendmail='~/bin/sendmail-mailx-hook' -s "subject" xxxxx@gmail.com < test.html
```

This method is more effective than proposed by @Gilles because it does not create temporary files and just fix the stream on-the-fly.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the below scripts to happen

```
#!/bin/ksh

(
echo "To: yourmail@domain.com"
echo "Subject: Job Status"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo
echo "<html>
<head>
<title>Status of the jobs during the day</title>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style='width:100%'>
<tr bgcolor='#808080'>
    <th>Job Name</th>
    <th>System name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Job-1</td>
    <td>Sys</td>
    <td>Sucess</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Job-2</td>
    <td>sys</td>
    <td>Failure</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Job-3</td>
    <td>sys</td>
    <td>Sucess</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body></html>"
echo
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Comment: Nothing here is specific to `ksh`; you could change the shebang to `#!/bin/sh`. The path to `sendmail` differs between platforms; probably take it out and rely on your `PATH` instead (and/or check in `/usr/libexec` and some other peculiar places).

Answer (score 0):

For me i needed to specify a variable such as SMTP server, so the mail command worked in the below fashion. I searched across many posts, and i found below property to convert the body into text/html. Now the email i receive is in the HTML format.

> Content-Disposition: inline

Unix version: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

First. Create whatever information is needed into a script (testSql.sh)

```
echo "<html><body><pre>"
mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD -P PORTNUMBER -h HOSTNAME DBNAME --table -e "select columns from tablename where member in ('value1','value2')"
echo "</pre></body></html>"
```

Second. Pipe that script to the mail command

```
./testSql.sh  | mail -v -S smtp=smtp://IP:PORTNUMBER -s "$(echo -e "This is the subject\nContent-Type: text/ht ml\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Disposition: inline")" userid@email.com
```

By doing this i get information as below in the email:

```
Content-Disposition: inline Message-ID: User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08 MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit 

Value1 Value2
```

Value1 and Value2 as per the HTML tagging done in the testSql.sh

Comment: i needed \r\n on my Centos-8

Answer (score 0):

Posted in another thread but basically on our version of mail/mailx(12.5+) the -a parameter for mail doesn't work anymore since it adds an attachment and I couldn't find any replacement parameter for additional headers so the easiest way for me was to use sendmail.

Below is a simple 1 liner I created to run in our bash script that works for us. It just basically passes the Content-Type: text/html, subject, and the body and works.

```
printf "Content-Type: text/html\nSubject: Test Email\nHTML BODY<b>test bold</b>" | sendmail <Email Address To>
```

If you wanted to create an entire html page from a variable an alternative method I used in the bash script was to pass the variable as below.

```
emailBody="From: <Email Address From>
Subject: Test
Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"us-ascii\"
<html>
<body>
body
<b> test bold</b>

</body>
</html>
"
echo "$emailBody" | sendmail <Email Address To>
```

Answer (score -5):

```
cat htmlfile.html | mail -s "subject" xx@example.com
```

Comment: Nope. This will send a text email with HTML in the body.