# How to mailx working with Content-Type: text/html

Tags: smtp, mailx

I've to send a HTML file with mailx command but when I receive the email  with the mark up code showed like this :

```
    <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Title One /TITLE> <STYLE> body { width:900px; font-size: 10pt; font-family:verdana; 
.../...
```

I used this command :

```
cat file.html | mailx -r dude1@acme.com -s "Suject" -S content_type=text/html -S smtp=smtp.acme.com  dude2@acme.com
```

I tried this one too

```
cat file.html | mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/html' -r dude1@acme.com -s "Suject" -S content_type=text/html -S smtp=smtp.acme.com  dude2@acme.com
```

I got this error message with this last one above :

```
Content-Type: text/html: No such file or directory
```

What is missing in the -a option ?

Comment: Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15463/414186). You have another `mailx` version (Heirloom). If you type `man mailx` you can see what `-a` does: `-a file Attach the given file to the message.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mailx version is :
Heirloom mailx 12.5

This command solved my issue :

```
(echo "Content-Type: text/html"; cat file.html ) | mailx -r dude1@acme.com -s "Suject" -S content_type=text/html -S smtp=smtp.acme.com  dude2@acme.com
```